# Build sparse CSR matrix structure based on anticipated COO structure

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

**Introduction**

Note its not necessary to understand this in complete detail to answer the question.

I have a matrix `P` such that

```
P.shape = (N, k)
```

and a larger vector of random variables of size `m`, such that `P[i,:]` represents the index of the random variables that interact at observation `i`. Letting the inverse covariance of the random variables after all observations be represented by `H` such that

```
H.shape = (m, m)
```

we know that if `H` is sparse, it must have entries in

```
H[P[i,j1], P[i,j2]]
```

for `i in [0, ..., N-1]` and `j1,j2 in [0, ..., k-1]`.

**Question**

What I want is to build the sparsity structure of `H`, by considering `P`. I do not need to calculate the exact values of `H`. My current approach is to first build a COO matrix (using 0s as placeholders for data) and then convert to CSR as follows

```
# Build COO
col_idx = np.reshape(np.tile(P, k), [N, k, k])
row_idx = np.transpose(col_idx, [0,2,1])

col_idx = col_idx.flatten().astype(int)
row_idx = row_idx.flatten().astype(int)

indices = np.concatenate((row_idx[:,None], col_idx[:, None]),
                         axis=1)

A = sp.sparse.coo_matrix((np.zeros(indices.shape[0]),
                         (indices[:,0], indices[:,1])),
                         shape=[m, m])

# Convert to CSR
A = A.tocsr()
```

Now, the first part of building the COO matrix is very fast but the conversion to CSR is very slow. For my computer, using values of `(N,k,m) = (10000,50,40000)` it takes under 1s to build the COO but 20s to convert. My actual problem requires `N=300000` which I'm guessing will take around 30*20=600s.

Is this inherently an issue that is always going to be slow to solve, or is there some optimisation I am missing?

Comment: The `coo` matrix is minimally processed.  In some cases the `coo` simply assigns that input arrays to its attributes.  The `csr` requires further processing - lexical sorting, summing duplicates, calculating the `indptr` array.  What's the resulting sparsity of your matrices.